# wordpress - track when user data updated - hook not working

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

On the front end of the site there is the facility to edit / update user details which is done via AJAX.

I want to track the last time user data is updated and  have written a simple function for this.  However this isn't working and I am not even sure if the function is being executed.  I have tried using the following hooks but none work.

update_user_meta, updated_user_meta, profile_update

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
//add date / time to user meta data when details are updated

add_action( 'update_user_meta', 'updated_user_details' );

function updated_user_details(){

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'updated', $datetime );

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things wrong with this code that I can see straight away.

Firstly, `do_action` is used to create actions, rather than hook into them. To hook into them, you'll need to use `add_action` ([See here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/))

Secondly, as far as I can see, `wp_update_user` isn't a valid action that you can hook into. I think what you're looking for is `updated_{$meta_type}_meta` ([See here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_(meta_type)_meta))

So it would be something more like:

```
add_action( 'updated_user_meta', 'updated_user_details' );
function updated_user_details($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value){

     $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    //check to see if 'updated' field exists
    $updated= get_user_meta($user_id, 'updated', TRUE);

    //if yes update date /time
    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'updated', $datetime );
}
```

Note: This hasn't been tested but should give you some idea and some refs.

Comment: Also `update_user_meta` will just create a new meta row if it doesnt exist so that else part is superfluous

Comment: Well spotted @Mihai. I didn't actually look through the function content, just at how it was being called. Will update to reflect.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my function accordingly and use 'add_action' but still nothing is entered into the database when I update a user

Comment: I have updated the function in the original query.  Is it supposed to be 'updated_user_meta' or 'update_user_meta' in add_action?  I have tried both and neither work.

Comment: @LeeTee Use `add_action( 'init', 'updated_user_details' );`

Comment: @Mihai, tried using init and the hook works but  update_user_meta returns false and I have no idea why.

Comment: You're using update_user_meta inside the hook wouldn't that create an infinite loop?